# FlowExecutionException when a caught exception occurs in ItemWriter implementing StepListener

Tags: spring-batch

I am having an exception caused in Spring Batch code that I suspect is due to some bad configuration. First I will give context and then the problem I am having.

I am using Spring Batch 2.2.6.RELEASE

I have a job defined like this (simplified excerpts that I consider are the relevant ones):

```
....    

<batch:job id="job1">
    <batch:step id="step1">        
        <batch:tasklet ref="myTasklet1"/>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2" >
        <batch:tasklet ref="myTasklet2"/>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step3">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="myReader" processor="myProcessor" writer="myCompositeWriter" commit-interval="10" />
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="myWriter2" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step4" >
        <batch:tasklet ref="myTasklet4"/>
    </batch:step>

</batch:job>

...

<bean id="myCompositeWriter " class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myWriter1" />
            <ref bean="myWriter2" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myWriter2" class="my.test.MyWriter2" scope="step" />

...
```

The simplified writer2 as follows:

```java
public class MyWriter2 implements ItemWriter<Object>, StepExecutionListener {

    private ExecutionContext jobContext;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        this.jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Object> items) {
        try {
            // database insertion
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // add exception to context for later notifications
            jobContext.put("writer2_error", e);
        }
     }
 }
```

Some requirements:

- Need to access the jobContext from all tasklets and from writer2. Accessing the jobcontext from tasklets is straightforward. The writer2 implements StepExecutionListener and it is registered as a listener in step3 to be able to access it.
- The writer2 inserts data into a database. This operation may fail but should allow the job to continue the execution and if everything else works fine then the job should end successfully. That is the reason why the insertion exceptions are all caught.

The problem:

If the writer operation in writer2 fails the exception is caught but the job fails after step3. 
In Spring Batch Admin console the steps 1, 2 and 3 statuses are COMPLETED, the step 4 status is NONE, the job status and exit code is FAILED and the next exception is shown:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly at
org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:141) at
org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301) at
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=job1 at state=step3 with exception at
org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:160) at 
org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:130) at 
org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135) 
... 5 more Caused by: java.util.EmptyStackException at 
org.codehaus.jettison.util.FastStack.peek(FastStack.java:39) at 
org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLStreamWriter.setNewValue(MappedXMLStreamWriter.java:121) at 
org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLStreamWriter.makeCurrentJSONObject(MappedXMLStreamWriter.java:113) at 
org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement(MappedXMLStreamWriter.java:241) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxWriter.startNode(StaxWriter.java:162) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXmlWriter.startNode(AbstractXmlWriter.java:37) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.WriterWrapper.startNode(WriterWrapper.java:33) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.path.PathTrackingWriter.startNode(PathTrackingWriter.java:44) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.ExtendedHierarchicalStreamWriterHelper.startNode(ExtendedHierarchicalStreamWriterHelper.java:17) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:62) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.marshal(MapConverter.java:57) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:65) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78) at 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63) at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.Tree
```

If no exceptions occur then the job ends successfully.

Any ideas why this could be failing?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure error is thrown by writer2 and not from the other one?

Comment: Yes, the writer1 is working fine. I even tested with a writer1 that does nothing.

Comment: Edited the question to add the line that was causing the problem: writing the entire Exception into the jobContext. Apparently for some reason is not possible to add large objects in the jobContext. Adding just the exception message instead the whole exception allows the job to run as expected.

Comment: @RGH, How did you resolve the issue?